# Disable Windows Popup when changing volume (From Javascript on webpage)

Tags: javascript, html, windows

So there is a pop-up that shows, apparently on Windows 8 and 10 when you adjust volume with the keyboard on any website. Example: Youtube videos.

If I have videos embeded in my website, is there any way I can disable/intercept that behavior. I'm still on Windows 7 so couldn't do much testing (I would think listing for key press and event.preventDefault would do it, but apparently that's not the case, can't confirm)

This behavior can be disabled for example in Chrome settings, but is it possible to prevent it from happening from the Javascript code itself?

Answer (score 0):

The bar is a *top-level* window overlay on Windows. You cannot disable it using Javascript, though the user can disable it by installing [HideVolumeOSD](http://wordpress.venturi.de/?p=1) .

Copy the following code into Notepad, save as a .reg file and run it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\Volume Bar-On Screen Display (OSD)]
"Icon"="DDORes.dll,-3011"
"Position"="Bottom"
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\Volume Bar-On Screen Display (OSD)\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\Volume Bar-On Screen Display (OSD)\shell\001flyout]
"MUIVerb"="Hide"
"Icon"="SndVolSSO.dll,-120"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\Volume Bar-On Screen Display (OSD)\shell\001flyout\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\HideVolumeOSD\\HideVolumeOSD.exe\" -hide"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\Volume Bar-On Screen Display (OSD)\shell\002flyout]
"MUIVerb"="Show"
"Icon"="SndVolSSO.dll,-124"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\Volume Bar-On Screen Display (OSD)\shell\002flyout\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\HideVolumeOSD\\HideVolumeOSD.exe\" -show"
```

**Note**: 
Just make sure the Target of either command is proper on your PC...

`C:\Program Files (x86)\HideVolumeOSD\HideVolumeOSD.exe`\